# On Hover Only Show Element Related To Menu

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my React Project, I have a menu with 2 main list/nav items, and wanted to have an element appear on hover, and also stay visible when the user hovers over the submenu. I'm able to get this working using both css `hover` and setting className based `boolean` of a state.

Question is, when the user hovers over the submenu, how do I get the element related to that menu to show? Right now, both elements show when submenu is hovered. I'm using `.map` to populate the menu and sub-menu items so wondering if there's a prop I pass in to control this?

Here is the code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import styles from "./nav.module.scss";
import "../../styles/main.scss";

const Nav = ({
  navItems = [
    {
      id: "",
      label: "",
      subMenu: [{}]
    }
  ]
}) => {
  const [ballColor, setBallColor] = useState();
  const [showBall, setShowBall] = useState(false);

  const handleHover = () => {
    setShowBall(!showBall);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <nav>
        {/* Start of Menu Items */}
        <div className={styles.menuItemsContainer}>
          <ul className={styles.navUl}>
            {navItems.map(item => (
              <li key={item.id}>
                <a href="https://www.google.com">
                  <div
                    className={
                      showBall
                        ? `${styles.ball} ${styles.showBall} ${
                            styles[ballColor]
                          }`
                        : `${styles.ball} ${styles[ballColor]}`
                    }
                  />
                  {item.label}
                </a>
                <ul
                  className={
                    item.subMenu.length === 0
                      ? `${styles.noDisplay}`
                      : `${styles.display}`
                  }
                  onMouseEnter={handleHover}
                  onMouseLeave={handleHover}
                >
                  {item.subMenu.map(subItem => (
                    <li
                      key={subItem.id}
                      className={styles[subItem.class]}
                      onMouseOver={() => {
                        setBallColor(subItem.ballColor);
                      }}
                      onMouseLeave={() => setBallColor(null)}
                    >
                      {subItem.item}
                    </li>
                  ))}
                </ul>
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
        {/* End of Menu Items */}
      </nav>
    </>
  );
};

export default Nav;
```

See [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nav-z3c04?file=/src/components/Nav/index.js) for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is an array of colors : one color for each main menu.

The following code is one way to achieve it, I am not fond of all these loops in loops, so it is merely a way to show you how to handle this, but maybe not the best:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import styles from "./nav.module.scss";
import "../../styles/main.scss";

const Nav = ({
  navItems = [
    {
      id: "",
      label: "",
      subMenu: [{}]
    }
  ]
}) => {
  const [ballColors, setBallColor] = useState(["#fff", "#fff"]);
  const [showBalls, setShowBall] = useState([false, false]);

  const handleHover = i => {
    setShowBall([...showBalls].map((bool, j) => (i === j ? !bool : bool)));
  };

  return (
    <>
      <nav>
        {/* Start of Menu Items */}
        <div className={styles.menuItemsContainer}>
          <ul className={styles.navUl}>
            {navItems.map((item, i) => (
              <li key={item.id}>
                <a href="https://www.google.com">
                  <div
                    className={
                      showBalls[i]
                        ? `${styles.ball} ${styles.showBall} ${
                            styles[ballColors[i]]
                          }`
                        : `${styles.ball} ${styles[ballColors[i]]}`
                    }
                  />
                  {item.label}
                </a>
                <ul
                  className={
                    item.subMenu.length === 0
                      ? `${styles.noDisplay}`
                      : `${styles.display}`
                  }
                  onMouseEnter={() => handleHover(i)}
                  onMouseLeave={() => handleHover(i)}
                >
                  {item.subMenu.map((subItem, j) => (
                    <li
                      key={subItem.id}
                      className={styles[subItem.class]}
                      onMouseOver={() => {
                        setBallColor(
                          [...ballColors].map((color, k) =>
                            i === k ? subItem.ballColor : color
                          )
                        );
                      }}
                      onMouseLeave={() =>
                        setBallColor(
                          [...ballColors].map((color, k) =>
                            i === k ? "#fff" : color
                          ),
                          i
                        )
                      }
                    >
                      {subItem.item}
                    </li>
                  ))}
                </ul>
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
        {/* End of Menu Items */}
      </nav>
      ballColors: {ballColors.join(" ")}
    </>
  );
};

export default Nav;
```

And here is [a fork of your codepen](https://codesandbox.io/s/nav-p51xm?file=/src/components/Nav/index.js:151-165) as a demo of that solution.

Comment: I'm not worried about the color, just the fact that when you hover over the sub-menu, the large, half-circle appears on top of the other nav item.

Comment: Same thing: you want an array of booleans... updated.

Comment: Ok, makes sense. I'll review but this does look promising.

Comment: I wanted to ask you the logic behind `handleHover` function. Correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems like `i` will always equal to `j`, which returns `true`, which toggles the `showBalls` value from `false` to `true` and vice-versa?

Comment: Why would `i` always equal `j` ? This would be true only if there was only one main menu.

Comment: Got it. So `i` is the index of the hovered submenu, and `j` is index of `showBalls` array. When `showBalls` is running its' `map` method, each iteration checks if `i === j`. The case will always return true for the hovered submenu thus changing the bool value. All others iteration will be false, keeping the same bool value.

Comment: Yes, that is it